# Is "not very" considered polite?

Tags: adjectives, negation, politeness

I've heard that if you want to describe something in a negative way but polity, use "not very" + "negative" adj.

For example, describing a bad thing would be: This is not very good. Or talking about an ugly girl would be: She is not very beautiful.

So, is describing in such a way considered polite? If not, what is the polite way?

Comment: Politeness has to do with more than the phrase "not very".  Any time you discuss someone's appearance, or how something tastes, or someone's thought processes you're more apt to be impolite than polite if you do not choose your words carefully.

Comment: As to the girl, if you're describing her to a disinterested third party, you might call her "plain".

Answer (score 2):

Discussing negative attributes of people is *never* polite no matter how you try. If I said *that person is not very clever* everyone would know that I meant they were stupid.

The only way to be polite about another person's shortcomings is *not to discuss them at all*.

> If you can't say something nice about a person, don't say anything!

Comment: This is a good answer. But it doesn't say how to circumvent the problem if the OP indeed wants to politely describe about a person's negative traits.

Comment: That's the point I made. You can't circumvent it. You can dress personal criticism up in any fancy language you please, but it's still going to be rude and/or hurtful.

Comment: @CharlE  But sometimes you have to. Like a friend is starting a business and asking my opinion about someone. So instead of saying he's a lazy person, you want to be nice and say: "He is not a very active person"

Comment: If a friend of mine was starting a business and wanted to hire someone whom I knew was lazy, I would tell my friend the truth. Saying someone is "not very active" is simply you being "not very brave".

Comment: @CharlE man, it's just an example. And as mentioned in my question, I just "heard" and I wanted to verify. Not a very polite reply, pal.

Answer (score 0):

Talking about that ugly girl, an euphemism would be:

> She is not a top model (or a beauty queen), but she has her own kind of charm.

Comment: That has the listener wondering "Gad, how *ugly* is she??!!"

Comment: @Hot Licks: it also has me thinking, nobody I ever met  - woman or man - would take that as any kind of compliment at all.

Comment: @HotLicks - It shows that an apparently moderate expression may be a bit harsh.

Comment: The thing is, your listener gets more and more suspicious the more weasel-words you string together.

Answer (score 0):

This use of 'not very' is [weasel wording](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Weasel_word) and is deliberately disingenuous.

I upvoted the answer saying if you can't say something nice, say nothing; but if you must discuss appearance negatively, then there are more polite and less vicious synonyms for ugly.

Comment: No, it's not weasel-wording, it's simply trying to be accurate.  Things are not just black and white; girls are not just beautiful or ugly.